# Was this moderator deleted answer a mistake?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, moderators

I was about to flag a question as a duplicate because there is a question with a well written answer that I often answer that I often reference covering the same topic. However when I went to the question I found that the answer was deleted by the moderator [Andrew Barber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) on Dec 23.

Direct link to the answer in question: [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows/201277#201277)

Why was this answer deleted by a moderator? I don't see anything really wrong with it and it was a very good answer with 121 upvotes. The only thing I can think of is it was done on accident.

I would just vote to undelete the post but normal users can't vote to undelete moderator deleted posts.

---

Image of the deletion. the post is very long and would be too long to post here.
[image]

Comment: Holy Cow, I can't believe that was deleted.  Please flag for moderator to check it out.

Comment: Could you post a picture for us <10K please?

Comment: Looks like it might be. Perhaps Andrew will explain his reasoning.

Comment: All of the links in the answer are dead.  Well, actually, just the first three ones.  The Microsoft ones are OK.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah...dead links. That makes sense. Presumably, finding the appropriate replacement links would be enough to get it un-deleted, no?

Comment: Actually, just the first link is dead.  Some of the links are still good, but out of date.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think the links are dead, they are just not web links (yes I know the choice of using `http:\\ ` for the timestamp url is a bad choice but yell at the people who invented certificate timestamping). The first one just ignores HTTP requests that are not formed correctly to the API, the 2nd redirects you to the main page and the 3rd gives a friendly landing page telling you how to use it.

Comment: Quite right.  Anyway, that's what the flag that was cast said... broken links.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it standard for answers to be deleted *just* for broken links? I mean, even without the links(added over 3 years after the answer was given, by someone else), it's a **good** answer. Is it just a broken window thing? Wouldn't a simple comment to the still-active-answerer (or edit to remove links) be a better first step?

Comment: No, it's not standard @Geobits. This was most probably a mistake. It happens...

Comment: @Yannis I didn't think it was. The question here asked if it was a mistake, but from Robert's comments, I wasn't so sure. It sounded almost like, "Well, the links were bad, so...", and I wanted to make sure I had it right in my head.

Comment: I just edited the answer to de-linkify the timestamp URLs, since there's very little point in trying to open them in a browser.

Comment: Note that although this is now [meta-tag:status-completed], we still need confirmation whether bad links alone are enough to delete.